# When should I use C++ private inheritance?

Tags: c++, oop

Unlike protected inheritance, C++ private inheritance found its way into mainstream C++ development. However, I still haven't found a good use for it.

When do you guys use it?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Note after answer acceptance: *This is NOT a complete answer. Read other answers like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656224/when-should-i-use-c-private-inheritance/656235#656235) (conceptually) and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656224/when-should-i-use-c-private-inheritance/675451#675451)** (both theoretic and practic) if you are interested in the question. This is just a fancy trick that can be achieved with private inheritance. While it is* fancy *it is not the answer to the question.*

Besides the basic usage of just private inheritance shown in the C++ FAQ (linked in other's comments) you can use a combination of private and virtual inheritance to *seal* a class (in .NET terminology) or to make a class *final* (in Java terminology). This is not a common use, but anyway I found it interesting:

```
class ClassSealer {
private:
   friend class Sealed;
   ClassSealer() {}
};
class Sealed : private virtual ClassSealer
{ 
   // ...
};
class FailsToDerive : public Sealed
{
   // Cannot be instantiated
};
```

*Sealed* can be instantiated. It derives from *ClassSealer* and can call the private constructor directly as it is a friend.

*FailsToDerive* won't compile as it must call the *ClassSealer* constructor directly (virtual inheritance requirement), but it cannot as it is private in the *Sealed* class and in this case *FailsToDerive* is not a friend of *ClassSealer*.

---

**EDIT**

It was mentioned in the comments that this could not be made generic at the time using CRTP. The C++11 standard removes that limitation by providing a different syntax to befriend template arguments:

```
template <typename T>
class Seal {
   friend T;          // not: friend class T!!!
   Seal() {}
};
class Sealed : private virtual Seal<Sealed> // ...
```

Of course this is all moot, since C++11 provides a `final` contextual keyword for exactly this purpose:

```
class Sealed final // ...
```

Comment: That's a great technique. I will write an blog entry on it.

Comment: Question: if we didn't use virtual inheritance, then FailsToDerive would compile. Correct?

Comment: +1. @Sasha: Correct, virtual inheritance is needed since the most-derived class always calls the constructors of all virtually inherited class directly, which is not the case with plain inheritance.

Comment: This can be made generic, without making a custom ClassSealer for every class you want to seal! Check it out: class ClassSealer { protected: ClassSealer() {} }; that's all.

Comment: +1 Iraimbilanja, very cool! BTW I saw your earlier comment (now deleted) about using the CRTP: I think that should in fact work, it's just tricky to get the syntax for template friends right. But in any case your non-template solution is much more awesome :)

Comment: @Iraimbilanja: If you just make the constructor protected, the most derived object could also derive from ClassSealer (multiple inheritance) and it could call the constructor. That would break the seal. Not checked, though.

Comment: @j_random_hacker: after a couple of tries I failed to get the friendship right, I will try in a couple of days again. But now I am on holidays and will get on the road :)

Comment: j_random_hacker: Well, if you figure out the syntax for template friendship, I'd love to know about it because that would solve the minor loophole dribeas pointed out.

Comment: Actually, a bit of research shows that the standard explicitly says it's illegal to declare a template parameter as a friend class in paragraph 7.1.5.3.2. Damn. Why??? (For the record, MSVC++9 accepts "friend T;" and does what you expect.)

Comment: j_random_hacker :P will be allowed in C++1x .

Answer (score 162):

I use it all the time.  A few examples off the top of my head:

- When I want to expose some but not all of a base class's interface.  Public inheritance would be a lie, as [Liskov substitutability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) is broken, whereas composition would mean writing a bunch of forwarding functions.
- When I want to derive from a concrete class without a virtual destructor. Public inheritance would invite clients to delete through a pointer-to-base, invoking undefined behaviour.

A typical example is deriving privately from an STL container:

```
class MyVector : private vector<int>
{
public:
    // Using declarations expose the few functions my clients need 
    // without a load of forwarding functions. 
    using vector<int>::push_back;
    // etc...  
};
```

- When implementing the Adapter Pattern, inheriting privately from the Adapted class saves having to forward to an enclosed instance.
- To implement a private interface.  This comes up often with the Observer Pattern.  Typically my Observer class, MyClass say, *subscribes itself* with some Subject.  Then, only MyClass needs to do the MyClass -> Observer conversion.  The rest of the system doesn't need to know about it, so private inheritance is indicated.

Comment: @Krsna: Actually, I don't think so. There is only one reason here: laziness, apart from the last, which would be trickier to work around.

Comment: Not so much laziness (unless you mean it in the good way). This allows creation of new overloads of functions that have been exposed without any extra work. If in C++1x they add 3 new overloads to `push_back`, `MyVector` gets them for free.

Comment: @DavidStone, can't you do it with a template method ?

Comment: @Julien__: Yes, you could write `template<typename... Args> constexpr decltype(auto) f(Args && ... args) noexcept(noexcept(std::declval<Base &>().f(std::forward<Args>(args)...)) and std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<decltype(std::declval<Base &>().f(std::forward<Args>(args)...))>) { return m_base.f(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }` or you could write using `Base::f;`. If you want most of the functionality and flexibility that private inheritance and a `using` statement gives you, you have that monster for each function (and don't forget about `const` and `volatile` overloads!).

Comment: I say most of the functionality because you are still invoking one extra move constructor that isn't present in the using statement version. In general, you would expect this to be optimized away, but the function could theoretically be returning a non-movable type by value. The forwarding function template also has an extra template instantiation and constexpr depth. This may cause your program to run into implementation limits.

Comment: @DavidStone please see my corresponding SO question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28393195/method-forwarding-with-composition-instead-of-inheritance-using-c-traits

Comment: But one could write `const std::vector<int>& vec = MyVector<int>{}; ` and then call `vec.some_unexposed_method();`, which would then make private inheritance pointless...

Comment: @LanYi You can't. That's the point of private inheritance.

Comment: @LanYi only within the members of `MyVector`. Outside of it you can't

Answer (score 34):

The canonical usage of private inheritance is the "implemented in terms of" relationship (thanks to Scott Meyers' 'Effective C++' for this wording). In other words, the external interface of the inheriting class has no (visible) relationship to the inherited class, but it uses it internally to implement its functionality.

Comment: May be worth mentioning one of the reasons why it is used in this case: This allows the empty base class optimization to be performed, which won't occur if the class had been a member instead of a base class.

Comment: its main use is to reduce space consumption where it really matters, e.g. in policy controlled string classes or in compressed pairs. actually, boost::compressed_pair used protected inheritance.

Comment: jalf: Hey, I didn't realize that. I thought nonpublic inheritance was mainly used as a hack when you need access to a class's protected members. I wonder why an empty object would take up any space when using composition though. Probably for universal addressability...

Comment: It's also handy to make a class uncopyable - simply privately inherit from an empty class that's not copyable.  Now you don't have to go through the busy work of declaring but not defining a private copy constructor & assignment operator. Meyers talks about this, too.

Comment: i didn't realize this question actually is about private inheritance instead of protected inheritance. yeah i guess there are quite a bit of applications for it. can't think of many examples for protected inheritance though :/ looks like that's only rarely useful.

Answer (score 25):

One useful use of private inheritence is when you have a class that implements an interface, that is then registered with some other object. You make that interface private so that the class itself has to register and only the specific object that its registered with can use those functions.

For example:

```
class FooInterface
{
public:
    virtual void DoSomething() = 0;
};

class FooUser
{
public:
    bool RegisterFooInterface(FooInterface* aInterface);
};

class FooImplementer : private FooInterface
{
public:
    explicit FooImplementer(FooUser& aUser)
    {
        aUser.RegisterFooInterface(this);
    }
private:
    virtual void DoSomething() { ... }
};
```

Therefore the FooUser class can call the private methods of FooImplementer through the FooInterface interface, while other external classes cannot. This is a great pattern for handling specific callbacks that are defined as interfaces.

Comment: Indeed, private inheritance is private IS-A.

Comment: @Daemin, why don't anyone mark FooInterface as abstract? Interfaces are generally abstract.. isn't it.

Comment: @SouravKannanthaB I don't know what you mean by that. There's no abstract keyword in C++.

Comment: Yeah... Sorry for that.. I had just arrived from Java. I touched C++ way back. I just remembered C++ had abstarct classes and forgot there is no abstract keyword for that. Thanks.

Comment: @Daemin sorry for a late question. I tried the following: `FooUser ff;
    FooInterface *i = new FooImplementer(ff);`  There was a compilation error - error: ‘FooInterface’ is an inaccessible base of ‘FooImplementer’.  I don't understand it. Can you help?

Comment: You can't assign a `FooImplementer` to a `FooInterface` because it uses private inheritance. Your `FooImplementer` class needs to have a static factory function to create a `FooImplementer` but return it through the `FooInteface` pointer or a member function returning a `FooInterface*` which just `return this;`.

Answer (score 19):

I think the critical section from the [C++ FAQ Lite](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html#faq-24.2) is:

> A legitimate, long-term use for private inheritance is when you want to build a class Fred that uses code in a class Wilma, and the code from class Wilma needs to invoke member functions from your new class, Fred. In this case, Fred calls non-virtuals in Wilma, and Wilma calls (usually pure virtuals) in itself, which are overridden by Fred. This would be much harder to do with composition.

If in doubt, you should prefer composition over private inheritance.

Answer (score 4):

I find it useful for interfaces (viz. abstract classes) that I'm inheriting where I don't want other code to touch the interface (only the inheriting class).

[edited in an example]

Take the [example](http://www.parashift.com/c%2B%2B-faq-lite/private-inheritance.html#faq-24.3) linked to above. Saying that

> [...] class Wilma needs to invoke member functions from your new class, Fred.

is to say that Wilma is requiring Fred to be able to invoke certain member functions, or, rather it is saying that *Wilma is an interface*. Hence, as mentioned in the example

> private inheritance isn't evil; it's just more expensive to maintain, since it increases the probability that someone will change something that will break your code.

comments on the desired effect of programmers needing to meet our interface requirements, or breaking the code. And, since fredCallsWilma() is protected only friends and derived classes can touch it i.e. an inherited interface (abstract class) that only the inheriting class can touch (and friends).

[edited in another example]

[This page](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrivateInterface) briefly discusses private interfaces (from yet another angle).

Comment: Doesn't really sound useful... can you post an example

Comment: I think I see where you're going... A typical use case might be that Wilma is some type of utility class that needs to call virtual functions in Fred, but other classes need not know that Fred is implemented-in-terms-of Wilma. Right?

Comment: Yes. I should point out that, to my understanding, the term 'interface' is more commonly used in Java. When I first heard of it I thought it could have been given a better name. Since, in this example we have an interface that no one interfaces with in the way that we normally think of the word.

Comment: @Noos: Yes I think your statement "Wilma is an interface" is a bit ambiguous, as most people would take this to mean that Wilma is an interface that Fred intends to supply to *the world*, rather than a contract with Wilma only.

Comment: @j_ That's why I think interface is a bad name. Interface, the term, needn't mean to *the world* as one would think, but rather is a guarantee of functionality. Actually, I was contentious about the term interface in my Program Design class. But, we use what we are given ...

Comment: Addendum: I say interface needn't mean *to the outside world* since an interface includes both *services and attributes* but this is getting philosophical (perhaps lexicological) just like it did in my class.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes I find it useful to use private inheritance when I want to expose a smaller interface (e.g. a collection) in the interface of another, where the collection implementation requires access to the state of the exposing class,  in a similar manner to inner classes in Java.

```
class BigClass;

struct SomeCollection
{
    iterator begin();
    iterator end();
};

class BigClass : private SomeCollection
{
    friend struct SomeCollection;
    SomeCollection &GetThings() { return *this; }
};
```

Then if SomeCollection needs to access BigClass, it can `static_cast<BigClass *>(this)`. No need to have an extra data member taking up space.

Comment: There's no need for the forward declaration of `BigClass` is there in this example? I find this interesting, but it screams hackish in my face.

Answer (score 2):

Private Inheritance to be used when relation is not  "is a", But New class can be "implemented in term of existing class"  or  new class "work like" existing class.

example from  "C++ coding standards by Andrei Alexandrescu, Herb Sutter" :-
Consider that two classes Square and Rectangle each have virtual functions for setting their height and width. Then Square cannot correctly inherit from Rectangle, because code that uses a modifiable Rectangle will assume that SetWidth does not change the height (whether Rectangle explicitly documents that contract or not), whereas Square::SetWidth cannot preserve that contract and its own squareness invariant at the same time. But Rectangle cannot correctly inherit from Square either, if clients of Square assume for example that a Square's area is its width squared, or if they rely on some other property that doesn't hold for Rectangles.

A square "is-a" rectangle (mathematically) but a Square is not a Rectangle (behaviorally). Consequently, instead of "is-a," we prefer to say "works-like-a" (or, if you prefer, "usable-as-a") to make the description less prone to misunderstanding.

Answer (score 2):

I found a nice application for private inheritance, although it has a limited usage.

## Problem to solve

Suppose you are given the following C API:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

    typedef struct
    {
        /* raw owning pointer, it's C after all */
        char const * name;

        /* more variables that need resources
         * ...
         */
    } Widget;

    Widget const * loadWidget();

    void freeWidget(Widget const * widget);

#ifdef __cplusplus
} // end of extern "C"
#endif
```

Now your job is to implement this API using C++.

## C-ish approach

Of course we could choose a C-ish implementation style like so:

```
Widget const * loadWidget()
{
    auto result = std::make_unique<Widget>();
    result->name = strdup("The Widget name");
    // More similar assignments here
    return result.release();
}

void freeWidget(Widget const * const widget)
{
    free(result->name);
    // More similar manual freeing of resources
    delete widget;
}
```

But there are several disadvantages:

- Manual resource (e.g. memory) management
- It is easy to set up the `struct` wrong
- It is easy to forget freeing the resources when freeing the `struct`
- It is C-ish

## C++ Approach

We are allowed to use C++, so why not use its full powers?

### Introducing automated resource management

The above problems are basically all tied to the manual resource management. The solution that comes to mind is to inherit from `Widget` and add a resource managing instance to the derived class `WidgetImpl` for each variable:

```
class WidgetImpl : public Widget
{
public:
    // Added bonus, Widget's members get default initialized
    WidgetImpl()
        : Widget()
    {}

    void setName(std::string newName)
    {
        m_nameResource = std::move(newName);
        name = m_nameResource.c_str();
    }

    // More similar setters to follow

private:
    std::string m_nameResource;
};
```

This simplifies the implementation to the following:

```
Widget const * loadWidget()
{
    auto result = std::make_unique<WidgetImpl>();
    result->setName("The Widget name");
    // More similar setters here
    return result.release();
}

void freeWidget(Widget const * const widget)
{
    // No virtual destructor in the base class, thus static_cast must be used
    delete static_cast<WidgetImpl const *>(widget);
}
```

Like this we remedied all the above problems. But a client can still forget about the setters of `WidgetImpl` and assign to the `Widget` members directly.

### Private inheritance enters the stage

To encapsulate the `Widget` members we use private inheritance. Sadly we now need two extra functions to cast between both classes:

```
class WidgetImpl : private Widget
{
public:
    WidgetImpl()
        : Widget()
    {}

    void setName(std::string newName)
    {
        m_nameResource = std::move(newName);
        name = m_nameResource.c_str();
    }

    // More similar setters to follow

    Widget const * toWidget() const
    {
        return static_cast<Widget const *>(this);
    }

    static void deleteWidget(Widget const * const widget)
    {
        delete static_cast<WidgetImpl const *>(widget);
    }

private:
    std::string m_nameResource;
};
```

This makes the following adaptions necessary:

```
Widget const * loadWidget()
{
    auto widgetImpl = std::make_unique<WidgetImpl>();
    widgetImpl->setName("The Widget name");
    // More similar setters here
    auto const result = widgetImpl->toWidget();
    widgetImpl.release();
    return result;
}

void freeWidget(Widget const * const widget)
{
    WidgetImpl::deleteWidget(widget);
}
```

This solution solves all the problems. No manual memory management and `Widget` is nicely encapsulated so that `WidgetImpl` does not have any public data members anymore. It makes the implementation easy to use correctly and hard (impossible?) to use wrong.

The code snippets form a [compiling example on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26a22ee5803ca77b).

Answer (score 2):

If you need a `std::ostream` with some small changes (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/772355/1969455)) you may need to

1. Create a class `MyStreambuf` which derives from `std::streambuf` and implement changes there
2. Create a class `MyOStream` which derives from `std::ostream` that also initializes and manages an instance of `MyStreambuf` and passes the pointer to that instance to the constructor of `std::ostream`

The first idea might be to add the `MyStream` instance as a data member to the `MyOStream` class:

```
class MyOStream : public std::ostream
{
public:
    MyOStream()
        : std::basic_ostream{ &m_buf }
        , m_buf{}
    {}

private:
    MyStreambuf m_buf;
};
```

But base classes are constructed before any data members so you are passing a pointer to a not yet constructed `std::streambuf` instance to `std::ostream` which is undefined behavior.

The solution is proposed in [Ben's answer to the aforementioned question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19933011/1969455), simply inherit from the stream buffer first, then from the stream and then initialize the stream with `this`:

```
class MyOStream : public MyStreamBuf, public std::ostream
{
public:
    MyOStream()
        : MyStreamBuf{}
        , basic_ostream{ this }
    {}
};
```

However the resulting class could also be used as a `std::streambuf` instance which is usually undesired. Switching to private inheritance solves this problem:

```
class MyOStream : private MyStreamBuf, public std::ostream
{
public:
    MyOStream()
        : MyStreamBuf{}
        , basic_ostream{ this }
    {}
};
```

Comment: It looks like this behavior is broken at least in MSVC compiler. It allows me to override (and specifically mark it with override keyword with no complains) functions which are made private through inheritance inside descendant classes. Compiler also confused when several functions are met with same declaration via multiple private inheritance - the obvious way is too choose available public members, but it still chooses private and complains that they are incaccessible even if it has public ones. There's absolute no sense in private inheritance with this scenario.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how your comment addresses my answer. I especially never said that derived classes cannot override private virtual functions, that always has been perfectly legal. (see template pattern or [23.4 in C++ FAQ](https://www.cs.technion.ac.il/users/yechiel/c++-faq/private-virtuals.html)) Likely (private) inheritance is not the solution for _your_ scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it could be an alternative to **aggregation**, for example if you want aggregation but with changed behaviour of aggregable entity (overriding the virtual functions).

But you're right, it has not many examples from the real world.

Answer (score 1):

If derived class 
 - needs to reuse code and 
 - you can't change base class and 
 - is protecting its methods using base's members under a lock.

then you should use private inheritance, otherwise you have danger of unlocked base methods exported via this derived class.

Answer (score 0):

A class holds an invariant. The invariant is established by the constructor. However, in many situations it's useful to have a view of the representation state of the object (which you can transmit over network or save to a file - DTO if you prefer). REST is best done in terms of an AggregateType. This is especially true if you're const correct. Consider:

```
struct QuadraticEquationState {
   const double a;
   const double b;
   const double c;

   // named ctors so aggregate construction is available,
   // which is the default usage pattern
   // add your favourite ctors - throwing, try, cps
   static QuadraticEquationState read(std::istream& is);
   static std::optional<QuadraticEquationState> try_read(std::istream& is);

   template<typename Then, typename Else>
   static std::common_type<
             decltype(std::declval<Then>()(std::declval<QuadraticEquationState>()),
             decltype(std::declval<Else>()())>::type // this is just then(qes) or els(qes)
   if_read(std::istream& is, Then then, Else els);
};

// this works with QuadraticEquation as well by default
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const QuadraticEquationState& qes);

// no operator>> as we're const correct.
// we _might_ (not necessarily want) operator>> for optional<qes>
std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, std::optional<QuadraticEquationState>);

struct QuadraticEquationCache {
   mutable std::optional<double> determinant_cache;
   mutable std::optional<double> x1_cache;
   mutable std::optional<double> x2_cache;
   mutable std::optional<double> sum_of_x12_cache;
};

class QuadraticEquation : public QuadraticEquationState, // private if base is non-const
                          private QuadraticEquationCache {
public:
   QuadraticEquation(QuadraticEquationState); // in general, might throw
   QuadraticEquation(const double a, const double b, const double c);
   QuadraticEquation(const std::string& str);
   QuadraticEquation(const ExpressionTree& str); // might throw
}
```

At this point, you might just store collections of cache in containers and look it up on construction. Handy if there's some real processing. Note that cache is part of the QE: operations defined on the QE might mean the cache is partially reusable (e.g., c does not affect the sum); yet, when there's no cache, it's worth to look it up.

Private inheritance can almost always modelled by a member (storing reference to the base if needed). It's just not always worth it to model that way; sometimes inheritance is the most efficient representation.

Answer (score -1):

Just because C++ has a feature, doesn't mean it's useful or that it should be used.

I'd say you shouldn't use it at all.

If you're using it anyway, well, you're basically violating encapsulation, and lowering cohesion. You're putting data in one class, and adding methods that manipulates the data in another one.

Like other C++ features, it can be used to achieve side effects such as sealing a class (as mentioned in dribeas' answer), but this doesn't make it a good feature.

Comment: are you being sarcastic? all I have is a -1! anyway I will not delete this even if it gets -100 votes

Comment: "_you're basically violating encapsulation_" Can you give an example?

Comment: data in one class and behaviour in another sounds like an increase in flexibility, since there can be more than one behaviour class and clients and choose which one they need to satisfy what they want