# How to make a class Non-Inheritable

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Making a template parameter a friend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702650/making-a-template-parameter-a-friend)

C++ Faq 23.11 [How can I set up my class so it won't be inherited from?](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/strange-inheritance.html#faq-23.11)
lists the following code:

```
class Fred;

class FredBase {
 private:
   friend class Fred;
   FredBase() { }
};

class Fred : private virtual FredBase {
public:
   ...
};
```

I tried to make a generic template for the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>

template<typename MAKE_ME_NONINHERITABLE >
class NonInheritable{
private:
  NonInheritable(){
  }
  friend  MAKE_ME_NONINHERITABLE;  //<--- error here 
};
```

This give me an error:

```
xxx.cpp:11: error: a class-key must be used when declaring a friend
```

So I tried:

```
template<typename  MAKE_ME_NONINHERITABLE >
class NonInheritable{
private:
  NonInheritable(){
  }
  friend class MAKE_ME_NONINHERITABLE; //<--- error here 
};

class A : virtual public NonInheritable<A>{
};
```

And I get this error:

```
xxx.cpp:11: error: using typedef-name `MAKE_ME_NONINHERITABLE' after `class'
```

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: This approach is not realizable, sorry to be the bearer of bad news.

Comment: You will be able to use the first variant in C++11 (which changes friend stuff a bit), but so far the only compilers that seem to support it are gcc 4.7 and clang svn

Comment: @PlasmaHH MSVC accepts it as well

Answer (score 3):

You can use `final` from c++11 or `sealed` from microsoft extensions for c++.