# Can one template class can be friend of another template class in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I have a two template class, templateClass1 and templateClass2. I want to use private variables and methods of templateClass1 in templateClass2. Is it possible to do so by using friend keyword in c++ ?

Sumit

Comment: Did you try? What happened then?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is probably dead, but for other people who stumble upon this...

> templateClass1.h

```
template <class T> class templateClass2;    // forward declare

template <typename T>
class templateClass1 {
    friend templateClass2<T>;
};
```

> templateClass2.h

```
template <class  T> class templateClass1;    // forward declare

template <typename T>
class templateClass2 {
    friend templateClass1;
}
```

Comment: You missed a `<T>` on line 5 in templateClass2.h

Answer (score -1):

It is possible to have a friends of any type, but a template is not a type until its template arguments have been supplied.  So in general you would have to have a specialization for each full type you wish to be friends with.  This will push you toward attempting to pass the type to be friend as a template parameter, but you can not supply a template type that will be friended.

for ex. this is illegal

```
template <class T> 
class A
{
     friend class T;
};
```

with those stipulations it makes it very difficult to do anything meaning full with templates and friendedness.

Comment: The syntax is just `friend T;` since the compiler has already been told that `T` is a type.

Comment: You can friend a base class but you still then have to provided accessors because friendship can not be inherited.

Comment: In C++03 you had to say `friend class identity<T>::type;` rather than `friend T;`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702650/making-a-template-parameter-a-friend  From another SO question covering the topic

Comment: For every specialization of templateClass2 to be friend of templateClass2 or something else ? friend templateClass2<T>