# How to force use of curiously recurring template pattern in C++

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, crtp

I have the following base template class.

```
template<typename T>
class Base {
  public:
    void do_something() {
    }
};
```

It is intended to be used as a *curiously recurring template pattern*. It should be inherited like `class B : public Base<B>`. It must *not* be inherited like `class B : public Base<SomeoneElse>`. I want to statically enforce this requirement. If someone uses this wrong, I expect an error in the compiling phase.

What I'm doing is putting a `static_cast<T const&>(*this)` in `do_something()`. This way the class inheriting the template is or inherits from the class provided as the template parameter. Sorry for the confusing expression. In plain English, it requires `B` is or inherits from `SomeoneElse` in `class B : public Base<SomeoneElse>`.

I don't know if it's the optimal way to achieve this. Looks gross to me.

However I want to do more. I want to ensure `B` is `SomeoneElse` itself. How can I do that?

Comment: The `static_cast` doesn't enforce anything; it merely causes undefined behavior if `*this` is not actually a `T`.

Comment: @T.C. It does static checks. The one you are talking about should be `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: It checks only that `T` is derived from `Base<T>`, not `*this` is a `T`. i.e., given `class Bar : public Base<Bar> {}; class Foo : public Base<Bar> {}; `, your check won't catch anything.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make the constructor (or destructor) of `Base` private, and then make `T` a `friend`. This way the only thing that can construct/destruct a `Base<T>` is a `T`.

Comment: Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/702650/making-a-template-parameter-a-friend. It seems you can't friend a template parameter.

Comment: @Hot.PxL The top-voted answer in that question explains how to do it at the end (`friend T;`, not `friend class T;`).

Comment: You are right. But is there any way to do this where C++11 is not available?

Answer (score 5):

If your class contains some code that says:

```
T* pT = 0;
Base *pB = pT;
```

Then there will be a compiler error if `T` is not assignment-compatible with `Base`.

This kind of check is formalised in C++11 so you don't have to write it by hand and can get helpful error messages:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class Base {

public:
    void do_something() 
    {
        static_assert(
            std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value,
            "T must be derived from Base");
    }
};

class B : public Base<B> { };

int main()
{
    B b;
    b.do_something();
}
```

As to ensuring that `Base`'s type parameter is exactly the class that is deriving from it, that seems conceptually flawed. A class that is acting as a base class can't "talk about" the type that is inheriting it. It may be inherited more than once via multiple inheritance, or not at all.

Comment: I guess it only satisfies one side of the equation. I also want to make sure that `B` is exactly `SomeoneElse`.

Comment: This fails in all cases on clang3.6 it complains that the derived class is incomplete during the static_assert.

Comment: @RichardHodges May depend where you put the `static_assert`. I've added a complete example that seems fine on MSVC 2013. Will try it on latest clang when I get a chance.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker yes, it works when you put the static_assert in a function.

Answer (score 1):

Two good answers so far. Here is another which uses the idiom of generating custom access keys to certain methods (in this case a constructor). It provides an absolute guarantee of correct use while not exposing private methods in the base to the derived.

It can also be used to control access to other methods in the base class on a case-by-case basis.

```
template<class Derived>
struct Base
{
private:
    // make constructor private
    Base() = default;
protected:
    // This key is protected - so visible only to derived classes
    class creation_key{
        // declare as friend to the derived class
        friend Derived;
        // make constructor private - only the Derived may create a key
        creation_key() = default;
    };

    // allow derived class to construct me with a key
    Base(creation_key)
    {}

    // other methods available to the derived class go here

private:
    // the rest of this class is private, even to the derived class
    // (good encapsulation)
};

struct D1 : Base<D1>
{
    // provide the key
    D1()
    : Base<D1>(creation_key())
    {}

};
```