# Making an optional template parameter a friend?

Tags: c++, c++17

There is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702650/making-a-template-parameter-a-friend) explaining that a template parameter can be declared as friend with the following syntax:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
   friend T;
};
```

but what if in some scenarios A needs a fried and in others does not? Is it possible to make T an optional argument?

Is there a better solution than using some kind of FakeClass as T?

**EDIT1**: I found another solution:

```
    class B {};

    template <typename T>
    class A {
       friend T;
    };

    template <>
    class A<void> {
    };

int main()
{
    A<B> a1;
    A<void> a2;
    return 0;
}
```

but what if A is a complicated class with 300 lines of code? Is there an alternative solution without template specialization?

Comment: If A is complicated you could do one more layer of abstraction. You move all the implementation in an `A_Impl` class and jusyt inherit from it in both specializations of `A`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think befriending a dummy is the cleanest thing you can do, since you can't inherit or conditionally declare friends. You don't even need to create a new dummy type, since:

> [[class.friend§3](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.friend#3.sentence-3)]
>
> If the type specifier in a friend declaration designates a (possibly cv-qualified) class type, that class is declared as a friend; **otherwise, the friend declaration is ignored**.

Which means that you can pretend to befriend `int` or even `void` and they'll play along just fine.

<sub><sub>*This advice is valid only within the limits of the C++ standard and is not intended as a real life guideline. The poster declines any and all responsibilities concerning the application of the advice.*</sub></sub>

Comment: A<void> is a nice solution.

Comment: Dummies need friends too. It's not bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
template<typename... T>
class A {
    private:
        static const int i = 10;
    public:
        friend typename std::conditional<sizeof...(T) == 1, T..., void>::type;
};

class X {
    public:
        static const int a = A<X>::i;
};

class Y {
    public:
        static const int a = A<>::i; // error, A::i is private                                                                                                                                                 
};
```