# Inheriting from ifstream

Tags: c++, inheritance, ifstream

Can I inherit from ifstream and read the file from my derived class like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

const string usage_str = "Usage: extract <file>";

class File: public ifstream
{
public:
    explicit File(const char *fname, openmode mode = in);
    void extract(ostream& o);
};

File::File(const char *fname, openmode mode)
{
    ifstream(fname, mode);
}

void File::extract(ostream& o)
{
    char ch;
    char buf[512];
    int i = 0;

    while (good()) {
        getline(buf, sizeof(buf));
        o<<buf;
        i++;
    }   
    cout<<"Done "<<i<<" times"<<endl;
}

void msg_exit(ostream& o, const string& msg, int exit_code)
{
    o<<msg<<endl;
    exit(exit_code);
}

int do_extract(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cout<<"Opening "<<argv[1]<<endl;
    File f(argv[1]);
    if (! f)
        msg_exit(cerr, usage_str, 1);
    f.extract(cout);
    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        msg_exit(cout, usage_str, 0);

    do_extract(argc, argv);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect it to read the whole file, but it reads just one symbol (which is not the first symbol of the given file)...

Comment: good() !! What does that do ?

Comment: `ifstream(fname, mode)` should be moved to an initialiser list.  You should do some error check between trying to read data and using it, rather than only between iterations of that process.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772355/how-to-inherit-from-stdostream

Comment: In your place I would prefer aggregation over inheritance in this case, you can still use those methods without having to worry about what ifstream actually does.

Answer (score 7):

Don't inherit from ifstream. If you need to change an input stream's behavior, inherit from [streambuf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/streambuf/), then construct an [`istream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/istream/) around it. If you just want to add helpers, make them global so you can use them on ANY istream.

That said, your bug is in the File constructor:

```
File::File(const char *fname, openmode mode)
{
    ifstream(fname, mode);
}
```

This constructs an (unnamed) ifstream, then immediately closes it. You want to call the superclass constructor:

```
File::File(const char *fname, openmode mode)
  : ifstream(fname, mode);
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see an issue with your extract function but I do not get the point of deriving from ifstream.

The purpose of deriving from a class is to override its virtual methods so that when someone passes an istream& or ifstream& into a function (usually operator>>) your override gets called.

Unlike STL collections, streams do use a hierarchy and v-tables but newcomers will typically get the concept wrong.

For example if you want to change the buffer type it uses you would derive from basic_streambuf and use a simple istream or ostream object with your streambuf attached.

Changing the way the objects are printed or read is not something you can do by deriving a new class from iostream or streambuf, nor can you extend the iomanips, you have to use wrapper classes around the objects you are streaming.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a call to the base constructor. I think you mean this:

```
File::File(const char *fname, openmode mode) : ifstream(fname, mode)
{

}
```

instead of this:

```
File::File(const char *fname, openmode mode)
{
    ifstream(fname, mode);
}
```

Right now you are probably reading contents of some uninitialized memory. The second (current) code just creates a new instance of ifstream on the stack and destroys it right away.

Comment: Attempting a read on a closed stream does not give you uninitialized memory; per ISO/IEC 14882:1998(E) 27.6.1.3.20 `std::getline(char_type *, streamsize)` will always null terminate its result. Unfortunately, the code is not testing for the failbit error code after the read, so it doesn't realize it's getting a bogus empty string.