# Compiler cannot deduce which template type to return

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, output, fstream

The relevant code is :

```
std::fstream fout("Logs.txt");
class Logs;
typedef std::ostream& (*ostream_manipulator2)(std::ostream&);
class LogsOutput
{
public:
    LogsOutput() {}
    ~LogsOutput() {}
    Logs * pLogs;
    friend LogsOutput& operator<<(LogsOutput &logsClass, std::string &strArg);
    friend LogsOutput& operator<<(LogsOutput &logsClass, const char *strArg);
    friend LogsOutput& operator<<(LogsOutput &logsClass, ostream_manipulator2 pf);
    friend LogsOutput& operator<<(LogsOutput &logsClass, uint64_t number);
};
LogsOutput *pLogsOutput;  
template <typename T>  
T& LOUToutput()
{
                    if (pLogsOutput)
                    {
                        return (*pLogsOutput);
                    }
                    else
                        return fout;
}
```

I would like to call this function as such :

```
LOUToutput () << "Print this line " << std::endl;
```

Sometimes however the `LogsOutput` class isn't created, therefore dereferencing its pointer would crash in which case i would rather output to file instead.
I understand that the compiler cannot tell at compile time whether the `LogsOutput` class will be instantiated or not and thus cannot deduce the type of the template, but I don't see any other way I could make it work.
So my question is how can my function return a different type based on a run time condition ?

Comment: If you need to distinguish between types at run time, have you considered creating a function that returns a superclass, and returning one of two subclasses of that class at runtime based on whatever runtime condition you care about? Template instantiation takes place at compile time, resolving which implementation of a virtual method to call based on a class's specific type takes place at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complex solution to this is to use inheritance. If you were to inherit from std::ostream, you could return a common base class (Here is a discussion if you are interested: [How to inherit from std::ostream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772355/how-to-inherit-from-stdostream))

The simpler solution, imo., is to return a proxy class that redirects output as necessary.

```
struct LogProxy {
    LogsOutput *pLog;
    // ...
    LogProxy &operator<<(std::string &o) {
       if(pLogsOutput) {
          *pLog << o;
       } else {
          // Assuming this is available as a global.. You probably don't want to do that
          fout << o;
       }
       return *this;
    }
    // ....
};

LogProxy LOUToutput() {
    return LogProxy { pLogsOutput; };
}
```

A few other general comments:

1. If you want to use templates you would need to make this a compile time condition. You could use something like std::enable_if<> to provide multiple template overloads of LOUToutput() which choose at *compile* time where to log to.
2. I'm guessing it was just for the purposes of posting to SO, but your code has multiple globals declared in a header file. You'll need to fix that.
3. There are no const declarations on your code. A lot of those operators look like they should at least be declared const on their output (string,.etc.) parameters.

EDIT: Here is a working (compiles correctly) sample of this idea:

```
#include <iostream>

struct PRXY {
    bool cond;

    const PRXY &operator<<(const std::string &t) const {
        if(cond) {
            std::cout << t;
        } else {
            std::cerr << t;
        }
        return *this;
    }
};

PRXY pr(bool cond) {
    return PRXY { cond };
}

void test() {
    pr(false) << "Hello";
}
```