# Disable output of `progress_display` from boost

Tags: c++, boost

I have a function that uses `progress_display` to show a loading bar. I would like to be able to be able to disable the output for testing. The loading bar prints the second it is inititialized, and if I initialize it in an if statement, I get an error from calling `++loading_bar;` from another if statement.

I was wondering if I could disable it by initializing it with my own stream that does nothing, but I have no idea how I would make this.

```
#include <boost/progress.hpp>
int myfuntion(bool silent)
{
  int computations = 100;
  boost::progress_display loading_bar(computations);
  ++loading_bar;
}
```

Comment: IMHO this calls for [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). i.e. have two implementations of some progress logging interface (one dummy, one using `boost::progress_display`) and pass an appropriate one as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass an object derived from `std::ostream` in the constructor and the `progress_display` stores a reference, so it is not possible to change it afterwards.

As you say, you can create your own object that controls the output, but it must comply:

- It must derive from `std::ostream`.
- It must have the same time duration that the `progress_display`.

You may find more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19933011/218774) about the derivation from `std::ostream`. Based on the link, you may define the following `struct`;

```
struct Output : std::ostream, std::streambuf
{
    Output(bool enabled) : std::ostream(this), m_enabled(enabled) {}

    int overflow(int c)  {
        if(m_enabled) std::cout.put(c);
        return 0;
    }

    bool m_enabled;
};
```

Now, this `struct` can enable/disable the output from its constructor if you declare the `progress_display` as:

```
// Visible progress
Output out_enabled(true);
boost::progress_display loading_bar_visible(computations, out_enabled);

// Invisible progress
Output out_disabled(false);
boost::progress_display loading_bar_invisible(computations, out_disabled);
```

Comment: I had to add an additional `std::cout.flush();` after `put` to get this to work properly.