# C++ custom stream

Tags: c++, microcontroller, iostream, cout, ostream

How do I implement my own custom stream in C++?

Why?

I want to send data from one micro-controller to another using a wired connection and I think a custom stream is the most intuitive way.

Example:

```cpp
#include "myStream.h"

int main()
{
  myStream << "Hello world!";
  return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Solution:

```cpp
class Stream
{
private:
  // members
public:
  Stream() {}
  friend Stream& operator<<(Stream& stream, const Whatever& other);
};

Stream& operator<<(Stream& stream, const Whatever& other)
{
  // do something
  return stream;
}
```

Comment: It's just operator overloading.

Comment: If you want it to be std-compatible (to allow tricks like `endl`), start here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772355/how-to-inherit-from-stdostream

Comment: @szatmary It's actually not, not if you want to use all the existing operator<< overloads that work for ostream and ofstream and ostringstream.

Comment: this is a good question, but I will certainly forget to answer it properly.

Comment: If you want to use the standard `operator<<` and `operator>> `implementations, It is generally better to derive a custom `streambuf` class instead, and then you can use the standard `istream`/`ostream` classes using that buffer for the underlying I/O.

Comment: What is a "Wired connection"? Is it a lan wire, is it a usb wire, is it pio wiring?

Comment: @Ivanovic "one microcontroller to another" probably means SPI/I2C

Comment: Terrible idea.  Read your part's datasheet and learn about what "wired connections" it supports.  A custom C++ is about the worst way you could go about this.  Firmware programming done well exploits what the hardware offers and eschews "inventions" like yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at how streams work, it's just a case of overloading `operator<<` for both your stream object, and the various things you want to send to it. There's nothing special about `<<`, it just reads nicely, but you could use `+` or whatever else you want.

Comment: When I try to overload `operator<<`, I get the error `error: invalid operands of types ‘Stream()’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<<’`

Comment: It's worth opening up a new question with code that can reproduce that problem. You will likely need to have a few other questions answered before you've wrapped this up.

Comment: @tadman Actually your idea does not allow all of the standard library's existing stream functionality to work. It *is* possible to make your own stream that automagically works like ofstream/ostringstream/etc, so you can write ints to it as decimal, set formatting options, etc.

Comment: @user253751 You can make your own entirely independent "stream" system, or you can leverage the existing one and make a stream-compatible one. Both approaches have their utility. I interpreted "custom stream" as not compatible, but independent.