# Is it okay to initialize a std::iostream with a NULL streambuf?

Tags: c++, iostream, streambuf

I'd like to use `std::iostream` with file descriptors.  Unfortunately, since there's no portable way to get file descriptors other than 0-2 into or (at least until C++26) out of an `fstream`, I had to implement my own streambuf type, which I called `fdstreambuf`.  I would now like to implement an `fdstream` like this:

```cpp
struct fdstream : public std::iostream {
  fdstreambuf buf_;
  fdstream(int fd) : buf_(fd) { rdbuf(&buf_); }
};
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work, because `std::iostream` doesn't have a default constructor.  When I look at how gcc's libstdc++ implements things like ostringstream, it uses a default constructor for `ostream` that uses `0` for the `streambuf*`, even though such a constructor is not part of the C++ specification.  I can do the same for an `iostream` by passing in `nullptr` for the `streambuf` initially.  (Since `buf_` won't be initialized before the supertype, I don't want to initialize the supertype with `&buf_`.)  So right now this seems to work:

```cpp
  fdstream(int fd) : std::iostream(nullptr), buf_(fd) { rdbuf(&buf_); }
```

My question: is the above code legal?  And if not, how are you supposed to define an `iostream` type that includes its own streambuf type as a structure field?

I guess another question would be am I missing some other way to access file descriptors?  It seems very unfortunate that the C++ spec requires the standard library to provide streambufs that work with file descriptors, since cin, cout, and cerr have to exist, but it also prevents code from getting access to the file descriptors.  So if you need to open a file with `O_CLOEXEC`, or receive a file descriptor over a Unix-domain socket, or call `fsync` or `fstat` or `fchmod` on a file descriptor, you basically need to duplicate a bunch of logic that's already in the standard library to use iostream.

Comment: It is perfectly OK for a streambuf to be a null pointer. There are several places in the standard that say "if rdbuf() is not a null pointer, <do something>" (implying "if it is, do nothing").

Comment: You probably also need to inherit from std::stream_buf see [how to inherit from std::stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772355/how-to-inherit-from-stdostream).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Technically, it's undefined behaviour :P

Comment: @PasserBy Technically true is the best kind of true, but it is not true, technically or otherwise. Read these passages.

Comment: The behavior of passing a null pointer to `std::iostream`'s ctor is documented. The pointer gets passed through to `ios_base::init()`. Then in `init`, `goodbit` is set in the stream's state if you passed a non-null pointer, and `badbit` is set if it's a null pointer. ([basic.ios.cons]). So no, it's not undefined behavior--the behavior is clearly defined. The behavior of the stream otherwise is mostly "when badbit is set, do nothing" (until `clear()` is called to clear `badbit`).

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I was referring to the "implying" part of your sentence. Omission of defined behaviour is undefined behaviour, not implication of defined behaviour. I didn't read the standard on iostreams.

Comment: @PasserBy The word "implying" does not in any way mean that defined behaviour is omitted. It means that the behaviour is implied.