# Multilevel inheritance member accessing

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance

I'm learning OOP and it seems that I have encountered a problem.
CODE:

```
class line {
protected:
    double a;
public:

    line() {a = 1;}
    line(double var1) {a = var1;}
};

class rectangle: private line {
protected:
    double b;
public:
    double area() {return a * b;}

    rectangle():line() {b = 1;}
    rectangle(double var1):line(var1) {b = var1;}
    rectangle(double var1, double var2):line(var1) {b = var2;}
};

class parallelepiped: private rectangle{
private:
    double c;
public:
    double volume() {return area() * c;}
    void print() {  cout << "Parallelepiped rectangle information:" << endl;
                    cout << "a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ", c = " << c << endl;
                    cout << "Volume: " << volume() << endl << endl;}

    parallelepiped():rectangle() {c = 1;}
    parallelepiped(double var1):rectangle(var1) {c = var1;}
    parallelepiped(double var1, double var2):rectangle(var1) {c = var2;}
    parallelepiped(double var1, double var2, double var3):rectangle(var1, var2) {c = var3;}
};
```

Problem: error: 'double line::a' is protected within print().
Any way to print out 'a', and any general tips for learner?

Comment: Are you learning general OOP or C++? Based on that I could give some advice.

Comment: `using line::a;`  in the scope of class `rectangle`, or not using `private` inheritance at all

Comment: Why are you using private inheritance ?

Comment: In addition to the other comments, you might want to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance

Comment: @Claudio, to my understanding, if i want to inherit protected/private variables I have to use private?

Comment: You're misunderstanding how private inheritance works: read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1372858/2214693

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When learning OOP in C++ you don't need to use private inheritance. There are cases where private or protected inheritance are good design decisions but not when just starting out.

You should use public inheritance if you want to access members from superclasses

```
class rectangle: public line {};
class parallelepiped: public rectangle {};
```

Here's an SO explanation about the differences between private public and protected inheritance:

[Difference between private, public, and protected inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance)

Comment: Why should a rectangle be a sub-class of line? A rectangle is not a line. It is composed of lines, but that is composition and not inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

In most of the cases there is no need of using private inheritance.
Simply you want to use private inheritance when you want to hide to the user some methods that you have inherited from the other class.

Please find a very nice explanation here:
[When should I use C++ private inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656224/when-should-i-use-c-private-inheritance/675451#675451)

As a beginner I am pretty sure you will not need this in a near future.

Answer (score 0):

Private member, which is available in the current class and friend class, is unavailable in the derived calss.

It's ok to print out 'a', when **class rectangle: private line** is changed to **class rectangle: public line**.

Be careful to use private inheritance.