# Why override under private inheritance?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
class Base {
public:
   virtual void f() {}
};

class Derived : private Base {
public:
   void f() override {}
};
```

My question is there any use to such override? Private inheritance implies that you can not store `Derived` in `Base` pointer and thus it will never be needed to dynamically dispatch `f` to the correct type.

Comment: Hint: Some method in `Base` calls `this->f()`. Does it call `Base::f()` or `Derived::f()`?

Comment: you can use C-style cast to store `Derived*` in `Base*`, actually.

Comment: @Ven: You can use C-style casts to store almost anything into anything. You won't always get defined behavior, though ;-).

Comment: well, that's the one use-case for a C-style cast rather than a `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: It seems like a wonderfully useful feature for coding interviews, no?

Comment: @AmiTavory I have 2 interviews next week and this popped into my head lastnight  =)

Comment: This one seems pretty reasonable to me:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/676725/4885321

Comment: @alagner I don't see where the function "DoSomething" is dynamically dispatched in your link :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just one example: A function of `Derived::f1()` can call a (public or protected) functions of `Base::f2()`, which in turn can call `f()`. In this case, dynamic dispatch is needed.

Here is an example code:

```
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;

class Base {
  public:
    virtual void f()  { 
      cout << "Base::f() called.\n"; 
    }
    void f2() { 
      f(); // Here, a dynamic dispatch is done!
    }
};

class Derived:private Base {
  public:
    void f() override { 
      cout << "Derived::f() called.\n"; 
    }
    void f1() { 
      Base::f2(); 
    }
};

int main() {
  Derived D;
  D.f1();
  Base    B;
  B.f2();
}
```

Output:

```
Derived::f() called
Base::f() called
```

Comment: Can you provide an example or complete the example above please?

Comment: In your example if I understood correctly,  Base::f will always be called.

Comment: @mkmostafa: OK, I added an example. Just compile it and convince yourself.

Comment: basically inside  f1 instead of calling f directly you forwarded the call to the base to invoke the dynamic dispatcher