# How do I access privately inherited class members in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, private-inheritance

I'm trying to understand the private inheritance concept.

So far everywhere I see they write that private inheritance makes its members inaccessible from the derived class.

Doesn't this make it sort of useless? If I can't access the class inherited, what is the purpose of deriving in the first place?

Now I know private classes are actually used and helpful. I'm just having trouble in understanding how.

Comment: You might be interested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656224/when-should-i-use-c-private-inheritance).

Comment: "everywhere I see they write" Who? I have never seen such a claim. Please quote what you are reading.

Comment: "Doesn't this make it sort of useless?" - no. The member can still be used by calling a method from the father class which uses it. Essentially, this says "this member is for a functionality that is not to be ever touched by any child class".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question reads as if `private` members would be useless altogether. I mean you could as well ask, what is a private member good for if it cannot be accessed from outside. However, a class (usually) has more than what a subclass can use.

Consider this simple example:

```
struct foo {
    void print(); 
};

struct bar : private foo {
    void print_bar() {
        std::cout << " blablabla \n";
        print();
        std::cout << " bblablabla \n";
    }
};
```

A class inheriting from `bar` wont even notice that `bar` inherits from `foo`. Nevertheless, it does make sense for `bar` to inherit from `foo`, because it uses its functionality.

Note that private inheritance is actually closer to composition rather than public inheritance, and the above could also be

```
struct bar { 
    foo f;
    void print_bar() {
        std::cout << " blablabla \n";
        print();
        std::cout << " bblablabla \n";
    }
};
```

> How do I access privately inherited class members in C++?

Outside of the class: You dont, thats what the `private` is for. It's not different for private members or private methods in general, they are there for a reason, you just cannot access them from outside.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed rare to want private inheritance, but sometimes you do want users of your class to not be able to reach members of the base class.

For example, I use Boost (www.boost.org) for my date class, but I don't want that exposed to users of my date class, since one day I might want to switch out Boost for something else.

Answer (score 1):

Private inheritance is a way to model a has-a relationship. The usual alternative to model this is composition, which should be used when possible. Private inheritance is useful to model the has-a relationship when protected members of a class are involved.

A different way of framing it is "we want to use the implementation of this class, but ignore its interface".

(My experience with this is limited and this is what I recall from Scotty Meyers Effective C++, as there never arose a case where I would have prefered private inheritance over composition)