# Why should you check if Base is a private or protected base of Derived?

Tags: c++, inheritance, type-traits

The only difference between `std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>` and `std::is_convertible<Derived*, const volatile Base*>` is that the former is true also when `Base` is a **private or protected** base class of `Derived`. But, when do you really need to know if `Base` is a private or protected base? Why should the user care about internal implementation of a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As one example, consider

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo : T, Bar {};
```

In this case it is no longer an implementation detail whether `T` does inherit from `Bar` (or any other class) even if the inheritance is protected.

For private inheritance, consider a base class that does some book-keeping. For example creating log entries every time an instance is created. Now again, when I inherit from a second type as in `template <typename T> struct Foo : T {};` I want to know if `T` already inherits from the bookkeeping class or if I have to add that myself.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumptions are wrong.

1. `std::is_convertible` covers way more use cases than `std::is_base_of`.

   It also works for user-defined conversion operator as well as
   primitives.

   https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/JULbVf
2. If a class privately inherits a Base class that's not an internal implementation detail, but has effect on the public interface of the class. For example the fact that conversion to the base class is prevented.

Comment: i dont really understand your second point. If a class does not inherit from `Base` you also cannot convert to `Base`. Whats the difference?

Comment: You might want to check out use cases for private inheritance.

https://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/private_inheritance.php

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/656224/when-should-i-use-c-private-inheritance

Comment: i think I know what is private inheritance. I think the misunderstanding is, it is an implementation details when a class inherits privately while I suppose your interpretation is: It is not an implementation details whether inheritance is private or public. Consider you get a `struct Foo : private Bar {};` then from the public interface you cannot tell if `Foo` does inherit from `Bar` or not.

Comment: I didn't say that there is only one difference between `std::is_base_of` and `std::is_convertible`, I said that there is only one difference between `std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>` and `std::is_convertible<Derived*, const volatile Base*>`. As idclev 463035818 pointed out, conversion from `Base*` to `Derived*` is allowed if **and only if** `Base` is a public and unambiguous base of `Derived`, in any other case the conversion is always prevented

Answer (score 0):

The following class:

```
class C
{
    operator int() { return 0; }
};
```

is convertible to int:

```
constexpr bool is_int = std::is_convertible_v<C, int>; // true
```

Yet int is not the base of C:

```
constexpr bool is_base = std::is_base_of_v<int, C>; // false
```

So your premise, that the only reason for these functions to exist is:

> But, when do you really need to know if Base is a private or protected base? Why should the user care about internal implementation of a class?

is incorrect. There are other use cases.

Comment: I didn't say that there is only one difference between `std::is_base_of` and `std::is_convertible`, I said that there is only one difference between `std::is_base_of<Base, Derived>` and `std::is_convertible<Derived*, const volatile Base*>`. Furthermore, `constexpr bool is_base = std::is_base_of<int, C>;` is not an error, its value is defined and it's false!

Comment: @user7769147 You start out the question with: "The only difference between ..." that looks to me like "one". Anyway, You're right about `is_base_of`, it should be `is_base_of_v` to fix the compilation error.