# Why are we using access modifiers in heritage in c++?

Tags: c++, oop

So, the simplest case:

```cpp
class Parent
{
    protected:
        int p;
};

class Child : public Parent
{
    public:
        int getP() const {
            return p;
        }
};
```

Why are we using `public` here? I've seen it many times, but still don't understand what it does. It seems to me that `Child` can get access to protected attributes of `Parent` in any case.

Comment: ***Why are we using public here?*** Because a class is private by default.

Comment: Which `public` are you asking about? There are two.

Comment: Non-public inheritance is very rarely useful. It limits visibility of that relation the same way as it does for class members, so with `class Derived: protected Base` you cannot do `Base* b = new Derived` in `main()`, but you can do that `Derived` and it's derived classes. I cannot give any good reason for that off the top of my head, unless you want to only inherit members (in a hidden manner) and forbid polymorphism.

Comment: I now think the OP is talking about  this line `class Child : public Parent` which can be more confusing than the other usage of public.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Related: [When should I use C++ private inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/656224/580083).